# How to conditionally check and extract XML elements

Tags: ruby, xml, regex

I have to parse a given XML File that looks like this:

```
<country id='cid-cia-Ashmore-and-Cartier-Islands' 
  continent='Asia'
  name='Ashmore and Cartier Islands'
  datacode='AT'
  total_area='5'
  government='territory of Australia administered by the Australian Ministry for the Environment'>
  <coasts>Indian Ocean</coasts>
</country>

<country id='cid-cia-Azerbaijan' 
  continent='Asia'
  name='Azerbaijan'
  datacode='AJ'
  total_area='86600'
  population='7676953'
  population_growth='0.78'
  infant_mortality='74.5'
  inflation='85'
  gdp_total='11500'
  indep_date='30 08 1991'
  government='republic'
  capital='Baku'>
  <ethnicgroups name='Russian'>2.5</ethnicgroups>
  <ethnicgroups name='Armenian'>2.3</ethnicgroups>
  <ethnicgroups name='Azeri'>90</ethnicgroups>
  <ethnicgroups name='Dagestani Peoples'>3.2</ethnicgroups>
  <religions name='Muslim'>93.4</religions>
  <religions name='Armenian Orthodox'>2.3</religions>
  <religions name='Russian Orthodox'>2.5</religions>
  <languages name='Russian'>3</languages>
  <languages name='Armenian'>2</languages>
  <languages name='Azeri'>89</languages>
  <borders country='cid-cia-Armenia'>787</borders>
  <borders country='cid-cia-Georgia'>322</borders>
  <borders country='cid-cia-Iran'>611</borders>
  <borders country='cid-cia-Russia'>284</borders>
  <borders country='cid-cia-Turkey'>9</borders>
  <coasts>Caspian Sea</coasts>
</country>

<country id='cid-cia-Bahrain' 
  continent='Asia'
  name='Bahrain'
  datacode='BA'
  total_area='620'
  population='590042'
  population_growth='2.27'
  infant_mortality='17.1'
  inflation='3'
  gdp_total='7300'
  indep_date='15 08 1971'
  government='traditional monarchy'
  capital='Manama'>
  <ethnicgroups name='Arab'>10</ethnicgroups>
  <ethnicgroups name='Asian'>13</ethnicgroups>
  <ethnicgroups name='Bahraini'>63</ethnicgroups>
  <ethnicgroups name='Iranian'>8</ethnicgroups>
  <religions name='Sunni Muslim'>25</religions>
  <religions name='Shia Muslim'>75</religions>
  <coasts>Persian Gulf</coasts>
</country>
```

I have to parse this with XML to grab the `name` and `inflation` value ONLY if there is an inflation value associated with a given Country.

I have this Rubular setup here: http://rubular.com/r/L7pbX2mm1J with my progress. I have it returning back two matches which is fine, but if you look closely at the 1st match, the country is Ashmore and Cartier Islands and then look at the XML for that Country and there is no inflation - the regex just keeps going down until it finds an inflation value, then it closes it.

I'm wondering if there is a way I can have some sort of conditional operation that checks if there is an inflation key at all, and if so, grab the name value and inflation value...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look for nokogiri gem: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri.

Comment: https://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb I found ox 5 times faster than nokogiri, hence here one example in ox - https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431, search for any element and get it in hash form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use Nokogiri, an example:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('./country.xml'))
doc.xpath('//country[@inflation]/@name|//country/@inflation').each do |res|
puts res
end
```

if you "need" to use a regex, this one should do the job:

```
<country [^>]*? name='(?<name>[^']+)'[^>]*? inflation='(?<inflation>[^']+)'
```

Comment: For the regex part of the answer: That is, if the `inflation` attribute follows *alwasy* the `name` attribute, the attributes are always downcased, and the values are enclosed in single qoutes. And these are only the arguments against using regexes I got off the top of my head :-)

Comment: @Casimir, I took your REGEX and had to modify it a bit, but this is what I came up with and it worked:

`<country [^>]*? name='([^']+)'[^>]*? inflation='([^']+)'`

Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/csW2NLon9e

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regular expressions for XML. Instead, use an engine like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org).

Comment: @jScott you _have_ to use a regex? Why?

Comment: @matt For an assignment I have. I successfully used libraries like nokogiri and xmlsimple but was told other wise to use regex.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby standard library includes the XML parser [REXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/).